# Ambiguity error while overloading var args method and wrapper methods in java

Tags: java, overloading, ambiguity

I tried to compile following code but got error

```
static void test(long... x)
{ 
    System.out.println("long..."); 
}

static void test(Integer... x)
{
    System.out.println("Integer..."); 
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    int no=5;
    test(no,no);//getting error at this  point  in eclipse 'The method test(long[]) is ambiguous '
}
```

I donot know why it is ambiguous. means if I am passing an `int` value it should auto-box and `test(Integer..x)` should  get called..on similar line `test(long..x )` should be get called..this is my understanding..can someone explain this why it is ambiguous ?

Comment: What is the JDK version that you're using? And what happens if you compile it from command line? Please check if you're not bitten by this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7689819/2231632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` parameter does not match either of your definitions - one is defined with `long` and the other with `Integer` so it is left for the compiler to decide. Cast to `long` is equally valid as boxing to `Integer`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

Comment: Can you link it with JLS?

Answer (score 2):

Variable arity comes last in determining the most specific method. The rules to determine which vararg method applies when there are several are defined in [JLS 15.12.2.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) - here is an extract:

> One variable arity member method named m is more specific than another
>   variable arity member method of the same name if either:
>
> - [...]
> - One member method has k parameters and the other has n parameters, where n ≥ k, and:
>
> The types of the parameters of the first method are U1, ..., Uk-1,
>   Uk[]. The types of the parameters of the other method are T1, ...,
>   Tn-1, Tn[]. For all j from 1 to n, Uj <: Tj In your case, k = n, and
>   U1[] = int[] and T1[] = long[] so the determination can be made if int
>   <: long or the opposite.
>
> In other words, the type taken into account is not int[] vs. long[]
>   but int vs long. And it happens that int <: long so the int... method
>   should be chosen and it should compile.

---

Conclusion:

The code should (and does) compile fine with Java 7 but would not compile with Java 5 or 6. The code below prints int with Java 7:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1().m(1, 2);
    }
    int m(int... i) {
        System.out.println("int");
        return 0;
    }
    long m(long... i) {
        System.out.println("long");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `m (Integer... i)` which is in OP's question ?? [THAT WILL NOT COMPILE...](http://ideone.com/JTrTYq) and [here is the reason.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23364636/1686291)