# Why these varargs methods (which work fine in Java 6) are ambiguous in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

This code compiles and runs in Java 6 (IBM Java 6) but does not compile in Java 8 (IBM Java 8, and Eclipse's built-in compiler) :

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.test(true, new Object());
    }

    void test(boolean b, Object... objects) {
    }

    void test(Object... objects) {
    }
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
The method test(boolean, Object[]) is ambiguous for the type App
```

I found this problem while migrating a real application from Java 6 to Java 8. This code looks ok to me as varargs methods are usualy used as a last resort when Java chooses among overloaded methods.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Do you need the IBM Java version, or have you tried the Oracle version?

Comment: My Eclipse with Java 8 is fine with those declarations.

Comment: @AlexK. Mine is not.

Comment: @Tom I did not try Oracle Java.

Comment: The relevant section of the JLS is 15.12.2.5. Compare [Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5) and [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). Whilst I can't point to the specifically relevant change, the wording has changed substantially.

Comment: You'll find here the explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689386/why-doesnt-autoboxing-overrule-varargs-when-using-method-overloading-in-java-7

Comment: Thanks, it is the answer to my question and a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of `Object` type. Compiler thinks that boolean parameter is a subclass of `Object` (maybe because of autoboxing?), so it treats it as another vararg.